# ActionBar Sherlock SwitchWidget

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is there a Switch widget that comes with Android 4.0 and above in the ActionBarSherlock packages. I see ABS has a 4.0 compatible Spinner View, but no Switch. Does Jake intend to include this in any near release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `Switch` component is not part of the action bar and hence will never be part of ActionBarSherlock. The `Spinner` that is included is a subset of the full version which only has the necessary features required to work inside the action bar.

If you need a components like this on all versions of Android I suggest you backport it yourself. Just grab the source, styles, and drawables and fix up any usage of new APIs to use old or compatible method calls.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Found a project that has done just what you suggested. https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport. This is compatible with Android 2.1